# Stuck with Custom Pivot Model on belongsToMany relationship on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a many to many relationship with a custom intermediate model (pivot table). This is my model:

```
banners

 - id
 - title
 - description


banner_regions (Pivot)

 - id
 - region_id
 - banner_id
 - active


regions

 - id
 - name
 - slug
```

Eloquent Models code:

```
class Banner extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get all of the regions for the banner.
    */
    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Region', 'banner_regions')
            ->withPivot('active')
            ->using(BannerRegion::class);
    }
}

class BannerRegion extends Model
{

}


class Region extends Model
{
    /**
    * Get all of the banners for the region.
    */
    public function banners()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Banner', 'banner_regions')
            ->withPivot('active')
            ->using(BannerRegion::class);
    }
}
```

Banner Controller code:

```
class BannerController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Banner $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $region = $request->region; // region model instance
        // ??
    }
}
```

So, my question here is how to retrieve the banners for a particular region?

Comment: i'm a bit curious why `$request->region` is it an id? if so, perhaps `Region::find($region)->banners()->get()` will do.

Comment: Hi @BagusTesa, Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding :)

Comment: oh i see, well, could not you access the banners using `$region->banners()->get()` directly then? perhaps you would want to `dd($region)` first to make sure its the desired item..

Comment: @BagusTesa, It does works properly. However, BannerController is not the place to make the `$region->banners()->get()` query (SoC Pattern). Thanks!

Comment: @BagusTesa I've resolved my question. See my comment :)

Comment: i see, it seems the key lies on `public function index(Region $region)`. thank you for sharing, seems my Laravel comprehension pretty dull now.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

I've changed my code and now it works as expected.

I changed BannerRegion pivot model to be `Pivot` instead of `Model`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class BannerRegion extends Pivot
{
    // It is just for casting int values into boolean values.
    // Useful for JSON responses.
    protected $casts = [
        'active' => 'boolean',
        'for_customers' => 'boolean',
    ];
}
```

Banner Model. Nothing to add here, but I've made some changes in order to improve the JSON response, like `$appends`.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Banner extends Model
{
    protected $hidden = ['id', 'regions'];

    // Add data from the pivot model
    protected $appends = ['for_customers'];

    public function getForCustomersAttribute()
    {
        // Get the attribute 'for_customers' from the pivot model 
        return $this->regions
            ->keyBy('pivot.banner_id')
            ->get($this->id)
            ->pivot
            ->for_customers;
    }

    /**
    * Get all of the regions for the banner.
    *
    */
    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Region', 'banner_regions')
            ->withPivot('for_customers', 'active')
            ->using('App\BannerRegion');
    }

    /**
    * Scope a query to only include active banners for a specific region.
    *
    * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
    * @param App\Region $region
    * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    */
    public function scopeFindbyRegionAndActive($query, Region $region)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('regions', function($query) use ($region) {
            return $query->whereRegionId($region->id)->whereActive(true);
        });
    }
}
```

In my Banner controller, I just added:

```
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Region $region)
    {
        return $this->model->findbyRegionAndActive($region)->get();
    }
```

Region param is resolved by Dependency Injection (laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding).

Finally, my route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/regions/{region}'], function()
{
   // Banners
   Route::resource('banners', 'BannerController', ['only' => 'index']);
});
```

The endpoint:

`/regions/my-region/banners`

The JSON response:

```
[
  {
    "title": "a title...",
    "description": "a descritpion...",
    "link": "http://localhost",
    "for_customers": true
  }
]
```